# Fechamento de uma pergunta indevida ou não?

Tags: debate

O usuário fez uma pergunta sobre a função dele estar retornando sempre falsa, 
colocou código, explicou direito, e foi fechada como fora do escopo, 
sendo que  estou trabalhando na resposta com ele, o que faço em relação a isso?

[Pegar varios valores boolean e jogar dentro de uma variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/pegar-varios-valores-boolean-e-jogar-dentro-de-uma-variavel/)

gostaria também de saber o porque fora de escopo?

Comment: No meu caso que votei como fora de escopo é porque a pergunta como estava inicialmente e pelos comentário parecia mesmo ser o caso de ser um erro que só ia ajudar o AP. Com a edição e sucessivas dúvidas a pergunta transformou-se numa pergunta dentro do escopo. Agora está tão complicada que eu já não percebo nada da pergunta, nem qual o problema. Parece sim um ajuda progressiva de vários problemas. Mesmo assim não sei se deveria estar fechada. Mas vou-me manter fora disso e ver o que a comunidade acha sobre o assunto.

Comment: Poderia ainda ser fechada como não é claro o que você está perguntado e também Amplo de mais. Isto a meu ver.

Answer (score 6):

O "fora de escopo" é um motivo "guarda-chuva" para outros mais específicos. No caso, a pergunta tinha sido fechada com o seguinte motivo:

> Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

Não domino o assunto da pergunta, mas acredito que houve o seguinte:

- inicialmente faltavam dados para que fosse possível responder (inclusive o primeiro voto de fechamento era como *não é claro o que você está perguntando*).
- depois, o autor incluiu código demais; isso torna a pergunta tão específica que sua utilidade para outros pessoas é nula.

O segundo ponto isoladamente não é motivo suficiente para fechar (embora exista quem pense o contrário – eu mesmo penso assim muitas vezes). Eu reabri a pergunta, mas ficaria agradecido se você pudesse editá-la, removendo código desnecessário e deixando apenas a parte relevante para explicitar o problema que você explica na sua resposta.

Comment: ela não é tão especifica ao meu ver, mas há sim uma grande chance de não servir para ninguém mais alem do AP. 
porém ela já serve para o OP, e para quem respondeu, pois no meu caso estou aprendendo a cada erro que encontro, além disso, é raro, mas não impossível de aparecer alguém com o mesmo problema, ou parecido. 
no caso do AP é simplesmente um erro de lógica, mas não sei se devia ser fechado!
afinal o site é feito para ajudar não?

Comment: @Joannis fez agora um ótima pergunta +1. Deixa ver o que diz o bfavaretto.

Comment: O site é sim feito para ajudar, mas um dos principais objetivos é ser um repositório de dúvidas e soluções, idealmente que sirvam para mais de uma pessoa. Então perguntas com problemas impossíveis de reproduzir ou causados por erro de digitação são fechadas com o motivo que tinha sido usado nessa (e parece que foi usado erroneamente mesmo). Talvez essa pergunta não ajude mais ninguém ,as a sua última edição, melhorou muito a situação, agora ela está bem mais "palatável"! Obrigado! @Joannis

Comment: @Joannis, *ajudar* o AP é um efeito colateral do site. Para que a pessoa possa "sofrer" esse efeito sua obrigação é fazer uma pergunta que vai ser útil para futuros visitantes/pesquisadores ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Num mundo ideal é isso mesmo, mas a quantidade de perguntas *help desk* no SOen hoje em dia me faz achar que essa política não é mais vista como tão importante – infelizmente.

Comment: É fato. Qual será a escala de perguntas diárias que o SOpt poderia chegar a ter?</conjectura> Será que tem algum outro site sofrendo de "cultura help desk"?

Comment: Eu tento fazer help desk por chat. Respondo a pergunta conforme os dados fornecidos pelo operador, o resto é tratado via chat. Fiz isso já em várias perguntas, mantendo assim a dúvida inicial, se se justificar.

Comment: então mas se for um problema especifico do usuário ainda há uma chance por mais que ela seja baixíssima de alguém aparecer exatamente com o mesmo problema, porém ia ser basicamente impossível localizar a pergunta pois as pessoas expõem de forma diferente, 
o que torna a busca um problema sempre, ai voltamos a questão que por problemas de busca as perguntas ajudam quase que somente o AP em 70 dos casos

Comment: É mesmo uma excelente maneira de lidar com o problema, @JorgeB.

Comment: @Joannis o problema é que, por exemplo, nessa pergunta, a resolução esta feita via comentários. Mesmo alguém com o mesmo problema não vai andar a ler comentários. Vai verificar que a resposta não responde a pergunta OU que a resposta tem mais informação do que a pergunta pede.

Comment: @jorgeB, não estou me referindo mais a pergunta, mas sim a todas as perguntas com o problema.

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 pelo infelizmente. Precisamos ficar atentos para não haver exageros. Sabemos que a pergunta só ajudar o AP não é um problema, mas para tudo existe um limite, e embora existam erros como parece ser o caso nesta pergunta (apesar que não acompanhei todo o processo dela), na maioria das vezes o pessoal acerta em fechar perguntas específicas demais. Há casos que são óbvios demais que não vai ajudar ninguém. Sidenote: Não entendo porque algumas pessoas ainda acham que fechar pergunta é punição e fica pior que uma pergunta que nunca mais será localizada (não que tenha sido dito aqui).